# Password for default system user created in JupyterHub

Tags: linux, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I am running Jupyter-Hub with default authenticator and default spawner. Logged in to Jupyter-Hub with system username (admin). I added a new user called user1 in JupyterHub web console. The user got created in both the machine and Jupyter-Hub server as I added c.Authenticator.create_system_users = True in the config file. When I checked the machine users, user1 is added because of the above property added in the config file. Can anyone tell me what is the password for user1 as there is no password option to be given in Jupyter-Hub? I tried with empty, user1, 12345 and 123456.

I was trying to switch user by using su command. i.e su user1. It asks for the password.

when i cat /etc/shadow this is what i got,
user1:*:121212:0:99999:7:::

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the docs (https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/blob/master/docs/source/getting-started/authenticators-users-basics.md#use-localauthenticator-to-create-system-users), this option essentially acts like the `adduser` command. Even on command line this just creates the user, you cannot login to this user before you set a password via the `passwd` command.

Also, like the docs said, it is not recommended when JupyterHub users are directly mapped onto UNIX users, probably in part because of this password limitation...

Comment: Thanks for info @Louise